# Calculating the histogram of a matrix without using a for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, histogram

i have an image which i have read in and its pixel values are stored in a matrix. I am trying to get a frequency table for the matrix of which i intend to plot a histogram. I am trying to do this using only matrix expressions(i.e no for loops/ imhist function). I looked at a function called histc() that can count the values in a matrix, but i don't know how to use it. I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: `im = imread('path/to/imagefile');` If it is grayscale, you can then simply vectorize it and use `figure;hist(im(:));`

Comment: Why can't you use imhist? You could open the code of that function, and study how it is done.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
hist(image(:),min(image(:)):max(image(:)));
```

this will plot a histogram of the pixel values including the entire range of values that the image has.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is an old post, we can also use `accumarray`:

```
h = accumarray(double(im(:))+1, 1, [double(intmax(class(im)))+1 1]);
```

`h` will contain a histogram / frequency count of how many pixels are encountered per intensity level.  We take all of the values in `im` and offset by `1` as MATLAB indexes arrays starting from `1` instead of `0`.  The intensities for an image will start at `0`.  We also want to specify the size of the histogram to go from `0` to as many intensities that we have that is supported by this class.  We can figure out what the greatest intensity that is supported for an image by doing `intmax(class(im))`.  As such, the total number of possible intensities that we can support is `intmax(class(im)) + 1`.  The third parameter of `accumarray` specifies the output size of our histogram.

Take note that you need to cast the `intmax` call as well as the image `im` with `double` because what is returned is the maximum integer of that type **and it is of that type**.  Therefore, adding 1 will simply saturate the value and not register.  Therefore, you need to cast as `double` so that the addition can properly register.

Comment: I have a question about intmax(class(im)) where im is 'uint8'. For some reason intmax('uint8') + 1 always gives 255. Thoughts?

Comment: I had to do it like this ->
h = accumarray(img(:) + 1, 1, [256 1]); I believe you would need to check the type and pick the next largest.

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer yes because what is returned is an integer that is maximum for that type.... And **also of the same type**. Therefore, adding 1 to it will saturate and have no effect. You'd need to cast as double for it to work. Thanks for spotting the error. As such, wrap `double()` around the `intmax` call. I'll update my post when able.

Comment: One more thing... h = accumarray(uint16(img(:)) + 1, 1, [256 1]); It seems the issue of uint8 is super obnoxious. Matlab seems to be very old-school in the type department.

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer - Did you try the casting fix?  I've edited the line of code.  Try it again and see what happens.

Comment: Yes. It works, but you need to add it to both sides. h = accumarray(uint16(img(:)) + 1, 1, [uint16(intmax(class(img))) + 1 1]);

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer - I'm aware.  I've edited the post.  I would do `double` to make it compatible with whatever image type you're using.  `double` is the default precision so it'll handle any bit precision image.